# Graph isomorphism of two graphs that have isomorphic subgraphs

Tags: graph, isomorphism

Suppose we have two graphs that are isomorphic to each other (G and H). We also have the bijection between the vertices of these two graphs. Now we add one edge to each graph (G+e, H+e). Is there any easy way to find whether the resulting graphs are still isomorphic or not? And also find the bejections among the nodes? I truly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I think not. Knowing one possible bijection between the two isomorphic graphs doesn't seem to give a lot of information. If your bijection still works after adding the edge, then yes you know they are isomorphic, but if the bijection doesn't work anymore then either the two graphs are no longer isomorphic or there exists another bijection that does work.

If you also knew that the two graphs do not have any automorphism, then knowing the bijection would certainly help. Then you'd know that your bijection is unique and you can simply apply it on the two new graphs to see if they're still isomorphic or noy